# How to import single tileset image into xCode (Sprite Kit)?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, sprite, tiles

Example of tileset:

http://www.rpg-studio.org/wiki/images/9/92/Tileset.png

How to import these images into this grid in Xcode?

https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/06/AdjacencyTileGrid.png

The problem is Xcode doesn't understand that there is a lot of subimages inside parent image.

I've already saw a lot of examples which use tiled map editor but it has its own format and you can't design such levels in Xcode's visual editor. So they are not appropriate for me.

I also saw that people always avoid to use tilesets - they somewhere get a lot of separate images instead and doesn't describe what to do with a single big tileset.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution might be to just start with individual [images](http://kenney.nl) that can feed into Xcode’s image handling pipeline.

My understanding of the Tilesets you’ve described is they are produced from individual images with a tool like [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) which is then consumed by the [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org). The `tmx` maps produced by the Tiled Map Editor are consumed in Xcode using [SKTiled](https://github.com/mfessenden/SKTiled) for Swift or [JSTileMap](https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap) for Objective-C.

Comment: Can SKTiled be used inside objective-c projects?